# CHM file unreadble if saved to hdd

Tags: chm, windows-xp-sp3

I've just downloaded [JSon.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) for framework 4.0 as a zip file.
Opening zip (using WinRar) I'm able to open Documentation.chm file by double-clicking over the name listed and the help file is well done.
[image: Correct CHM file]

Anyway if I extract this file to hdd and I open it, help is unreadable.
[image: Wrong CHM file]

Sounds silly, but it's happening.
Thanks for your help!!!

**EDITED:**
Another tip: unreadble chm file is located in D:\.... (second NTFS partition of first hdd); if I save it on my desktop, chm file becomes readable !!! Crazy...

**------------------------------------**
**---------- SOLUTION ----------**
**------------------------------------**
I answer my question to close it and to help someone who finds in my same trouble.
Using tip suggested by @Marco van de Voort I searched Google for "chm unblock" and found this [link](http://www.drexplain.com/press/articles/error_accessing_and_displaying_chm_files_reasons_and_solutions/):

> **Your CHM files are stored in the folder with '#' (hash) character in
>   the path**
>  Many C# developers discovered that their documentation
>   and e-books in CHM format cannot be read because they were storing
>   their CHM files in the directories like 'C:\E-books\C#\'.
>  The hash
>   character signifies an anchor in HTML so the CHM viewer fails to
>   resolve the path properly and to retrieve the content.

That was my problem: I had path with a #... and I'd never thought this could be a great mess for CHM files!!!
Thanks to SO mates for the help given !!

Comment: I am sure you might have checked this, but still: are all of your files in same folder?

Comment: @vrrathod: chm file is the only one, it has no dependencies. Read my edited post. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows keeps track of downloaded files on NTFS systems, and puts certain restrictions on them. If you extract with windows explorer, this status propagates from archive to file. Using a third party tool (winrar in your case, I use INFO zip) can circumvent this.

Some descriptions and other links can be found

http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/chm_backend_for_fpdoc#Troubleshooting

Free Pascal (2.4.4) has some tool to unlock them. (chmls unblock). It is done by truncating an alternate filestream (therefore it only works with NTFS). I found this info somewhere on stackoverflow, but can't quickly find the link.

It might be that virtual folders like desktop don't fully support this.

Comment: Look at my answer and thank you so much for your help: you put me on the right way to solve my problem and to learn something I didn't know. :)

Comment: I don't know what to do with my question: I'd like to close it avoiding someone else wasting his time, but I'm not really sure I want to (or could) accept my answer as the correct one. So, if you copy my answer I can mark your answer as the one... Is there another solution in your opinion? Thanks again

Comment: Afaik feedback on the solution is usually appended to the question with a big separator in bold. Then the most suitable answer is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the references to some content is to web or no chm file. maybe if you can disassamble in CHM editor and change paths can fix it.

[maybe this can help you](http://www.taringa.net/posts/downloads/1603307/Editar-Archivos-CHM_-CHM-Editor-1_2_60.html)

Comment: Excuse me, but I'm not able to read link you posted: is it a private forum? Thanks...

Comment: Anyway, if there is something "wrong", file shouldn't be readable from ZIP file too... I'm stuck...

Comment: Thanks @iLevi, that software is really nice but didn't solve my problem. The easy way (for me) is to ZIP chm file and open from ZIP: crazy, but it works!! Ah, just a suggestion: are you sure that this chm editor has a valid license?

Comment: hmmm.. works for me... so so... did not know that you can open CHM like ZIP file...

Comment: No, I mean: if you cannot open chm file because of a wrong path, you can zip that file, open zip archive and double-click on chm inside zip: chm will be opened without errors!!

Answer (score 0):

There are security permissions applied to this file type by a recent patch.

you need to unblock the file:
http://www.helpscribble.com/chmnetwork.html

Comment: Your link seemed promising, but it didn't help. Anyway read my edited post and thanks for your help, I really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

instead of thinking many possibilities of "windows security permission", get a CHM reader or wrap your CHM using winrar, and doubleclick to view it like you did.

It's save your time a lot!!

So, two simple solutions are:

1. have a CHM reader: https://blog.kowalczyk.info/articles/chm-reader-viewer-for-windows.html
2. OR right click CHM file/s, > Add to RAR Archive.
   If you want to read it, double click RAR file > double click CHM file. BINGO!!